# Best way to (git) push changes to a development server and have it automatically restart a Node app?

Tags: node.js, git

Previously and on my local machine, I've been using `nodemon` which watches for changes made to a Node app and reloads it upon every change.  But running the development server on my own machine is no longer feasible, so I've setup git for the app on a designated development server.

In advance, I prefer Sublime Text, so editing files on the development server via the terminal doesn't match my workflow, plus I like having a copy of everything on my local machine by default.  I had also checked out `rsync`, but I like the fine-grained version control that git offers.

So how can I edit files locally, `git push` them to a development server, and have the Node app automatically reload after every push?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9691385

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a server side hook. In your .git directory there is a hook directory. Just cd in to .git/hooks. There you can write a script in whatever language you need to write it in. Essentially after you push it will run the script you tell it to. Here is more information on git hooks

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Quick tutorial to make this work:

1. On the development server, navigate to `/home/dev-user/Node` and initialize bare repository at `/home/dev-user/Node/example.git` using `git init --bare example.git`.
2. Clone repository into `/home/dev-user/Node/example` using `git clone example.git`.
3. Add files to `/home/dev-user/Node/example` as necessary, then `git add .` and `git commit -m "init"` and finally `git push origin master` which will push those files to `example.git`.
4. Edit or create `/home/dev-user/Node/example.git/hooks/post-receive` and add the following line:

   `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/dev-user/Node/example/ git checkout -f`

   This will automatically update the files in `/home/dev-user/Node/example/` upon any changes pushed to `/home/dev-user/Node/example.git`.
5. If you don't have `nodemon` installed already, install it with `npm install -g nodemon`.  You may have to use `sudo`.
6. Assuming your main Node app is located at `/home/dev-user/Node/example/app.js`, start the app using `nodemon /home/dev-user/Node/example/app.js` (or if you're already within `/home/dev-user/Node/example`, just `nodemon app.js` of course).
7. On your local machine, navigate to `/home/timbur/Node`, and assuming you're able to connect to the server automatically via SSH, clone the bare repository using `git clone dev-user@dev.server.ip.address:Node/example.git`.  You'll now have everything in `/home/timbur/Node/example`.
8. Edit files on your local machine and add/commit/push files to the development server as usual, and changes will automatically update the server's `example` directory, which `nodemon` will detect and the app will be restarted.

Comment: Thanks!  This pointed me in the right direction and I've got it working now.  Do you mind if I edit your answer to describe exactly what I did?  It's actually quite simple, as I had expected/hoped.  :)

Comment: no problem, and sure please do, it'll probably help someone else a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to setup a continuous integration server, like Jenkins: https://jenkins-ci.org/

And then there are plugins for basically whatever you want to do, like this one for node.js for instance: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

But that's probably not the easiest way. You could also setup a post-receive hook on your server, that checks out the code whenever you push any changes, and then let it restart your server. Here's a gist I found (but never tried) https://gist.github.com/tlrobinson/8035884